when working with an attorney to draft a provisional, do they also charge you for questions that they answer?
So if I ask questions via email to my attorney, they of course would have to burn time if they were to answer them.
What is the common practice in the industry?
Is it common for attorneys to bill their clients for the time that they spend answering their questions along the way of drafting the application?

Most of my experience with patent lawyers is with corporate attorneys. That said, my experience with lawyers in general is that they charge for whatever work they do. That said, if the question is something that can be immediately answered in say less than a minute they might not bother to bill, but if it takes 10 minutes, I'd expect it to be billed.

Some people charge a flat fee, others by the 15 minute interval.
